# Show maintenance page for a sub page on the website for a fixed timeframe

Tags: redirect

We are currently on **Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604** and have a website `www.abc.com` and it has a web page called `www.abc.com/a` and this is the page that relies on back end systems. These systems have a scheduled maintenance every week on a fixed timeframe for example like every Saturday 2am to 2:30am EST.

During this time, part of the webpage flow does not work but the page will be up and running so we decided that during this timeframe anyone trying to access the URL `www.abc.com/a`, I would like to intercept them with a maintenance page `www.abc.com/Maintainace.htm` and once the maintenance timeframe is finished I would like the URL work the way it is.

What is the best way to approach this scenario? can we implement a IIS redirect on the URL based upon the timeframe? any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be an idea to have the rendering(s) that rely on the backend systems handle this.. let them show a maintenance text.

Comment: Are you using some sort or URL redirect module that allows you to create redirect rules from within Sitecore?

Comment: @jammykam - Thank you for the response. Yes, we have URL redirect module installed, but I am not sure if we can redirect the URL based upon timeframe every week. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Gatogordo - Thank you for the response. The backend system is called at the end of the flow thats where it error's out during the timeframe and we are trying to have quick solution to redirect the URL to maintaince page at the begining of the flow itself during the downtime.

Answer (score 1):

I would not let a redirect module handle this as that would make systems rely on it. As you do have a "flow" in your application -with the backend system call at the end- I would add one part into that flow right in the beginning.

Add some code that checks the availability of your backend (can be time based or anything else..) and act upon that: when the backend is unavailable and you know the flow will not end, stop the execution and give a message to the end users. This can be a text message on the same page or a redirect.

This way you keep related logic together - it is some custom code but not that much.

Answer (score 0):

we use the Sitecore Healthcheck module for a similar scenario. https://github.com/Mitya88/SitecoreHealthcheck

The module provides different types of listeners to monitor availability of services, applications, databases, etc. We have some backend systems we keep tabs on using the API listener and some custom code that executes every time the status on a monitored service changes.